# count number of i such that ( (p_2*i) mod p_2) == l

Tags: modules, nt.number-theory

How to determine the number of $i$'s, as fast as possible, such that $1\le i \le L$ and $((a*i+b)\mod p) \mod k = l$, where $1\lt a,b\lt p-1, p$ is a prime number, and $l \lt k \lt L \lt p$.

This problem seems to be too complex, let me begin with a simple one:

given two different primes $p_1, p_2$, integer $L$ and another integer $l< p_1$. Is there any way to compute the number of solutions of $1\leq i\leq L$ s.t.,
$$(p_2i)\mod p_1 = l$$

we can assume $L=c*2^d$ for some integers $c,d$, because we can first use dyadic intervals

Comment: It sshould be close to L/k.  How accurate of a count do you need?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.09.26

Comment: Also, are a and k relatively prime?  Gerhard "Ask Me About Jacobsthal's Function" Paseman, 2012.09.26

Comment: Your new problem is easily seen to have the answer as either floor of or ceiling of L/p_1, and the method I suggest of using
a multiplicative inverse (over p_1, called) f of p_2 will help you determine which, by checking if L mod p_1 is at most lf or not.  Gerhard "Really, Ask Me About Jacobsthal" Paseman, 2012.09.29

Comment: yes, I realize it after this one is closed.. BYT, the way you propose for the original one is right. The problem is reduced to count the number of integer points in a triangle where the vertex is rational. thx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until a better idea strikes me, why not give this one a go?

Reduce the problem to $i + B \pmod p$ by the following.  Find $f$ so that $fa\equiv1 \pmod p$.
then transform the set $ai+b$ to $i +fb \pmod p$.  You will also have to transform the set
of numbers in $[0,p)$ of the form $tk+l$ to $tfk+fl \pmod p$, but if this set is nice you might
be able to find quickly which parts lie in the transformed interval.

Gerhard "I Saw This On ArXiv" Paseman, 2012.09.26

Comment: thanks for your idea, I will try your ways to see want I can get. I update a simple version, which seems to be much easier.(although I don't know how to solve it :-)

Comment: exatly solution is wanted, a relative error one might also work for my problem